# Parse data from all access log files to capture key value unix script

Tags: unix, awk

we have multiple access log file gun zipped with sample below. need to grab datefrom=, dateto= etc from file

```
GET /purchase Item?workflow/?datefrom=01%2F06%2F22&dateto=04%2F06%2F22&userId=20253471&itemId=23434300 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0" "198.168.1.1" request_time=1.843 upstream_response_time=1.844 upstream_connect_time=0.000 upstream_header_time=1.824
```

I tried below script:

```sh
awk '{ delete vars; for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { n = index($i, "="); if(n) { vars[substr($i, 1, n - 1)] = substr($i, n + 1) } } Var = vars["Var"] } { print Var, $5 }' test.access.log
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far and hasn't worked?

Comment: I tried below script: awk '{ delete vars; for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { n = index($i, "="); if(n) { vars[substr($i, 1, n - 1)] = substr($i, n + 1) } } Var = vars["Var"] } { print Var, $5 }' test.access.log

Comment: Your code works, as long as the `var=value` pairs are separated by spaces.  Your dateto and datefrom are included inside a single string.

Answer (score 0):

**test.access.log**

```
GET /purchase Item?workflow/?datefrom=01%2F06%2F22&dateto=04%2F06%2F22&userId=20253471&itemId=23434300 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0" "198.168.1.1" request_time=1.843 upstream_response_time=1.844 upstream_connect_time=0.000 upstream_header_time=1.824
```

**script.awk**

```
{
    gsub(/&/," ")
    gsub(/?/," ")
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        n = index($i, "=");
        if(n) {
            print substr($i, 1, n - 1) " : " substr($i, n + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

- the first `gsub` replaces `&` by a space.
- the second does the same for `?`.
- these `gsub` are to add splits in the input.
- the rest of the code is the same.

**Calling the awk script**

```
awk -f so.awk test.access.log
```

**Produces this output**

```
datefrom : 01%2F06%2F22
dateto : 04%2F06%2F22
userId : 20253471
itemId : 23434300
request_time : 1.843
upstream_response_time : 1.844
upstream_connect_time : 0.000
upstream_header_time : 1.824
```

You can put your variables code inside this awk script.